# Getting "ERROR: Double requirement given: setuptools" error in zappa

Tags: python, flask, zappa

I tried to deploy my Flask app with `zappa==0.52.0`, but I get an error as below;

> ERROR: Double requirement given: setuptools (already in setuptools==52.0.0.post20210125, name='setuptools')
> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/yoonshinkwark/Documents/JBR_reco_local_2/JBR_reco_API_2/dola-aldagram/aws-flask38/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> Oh no! An error occurred! :(

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/yoonshinkwark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 3422, in handle
> sys.exit(cli.handle())
> File "/Users/yoonshinkwark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 588, in handle
> self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
> File "/Users/yoonshinkwark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 630, in dispatch_command
> self.deploy(self.vargs["zip"], self.vargs["docker_image_uri"])
> File "/Users/yoonshinkwark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 852, in deploy
> self.create_package()
> File "/Users/yoonshinkwark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2760, in create_package
> venv=self.zappa.create_handler_venv(),
> File "/Users/yoonshinkwark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 513, in create_handler_venv
> raise EnvironmentError("Pypi lookup failed")
> OSError: Pypi lookup failed

The version of Python is 3.8.8.

Comment: I'm getting the same error since yesterday.

Answer (score 8):

There is already an issue in the zappa github:
https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/995

The problem is that zappa adds `setup-tools` to its dependencies but the latest release of pip-tools (6.2.0) does the same now.

As a quick fix, you can pin pip-tools to version 6.1.0 in your requirements.txt